# SVG convert line to rect

Tags: svg, rotation, rect

How could I convert a line to a rect by specially preserving the information about line's start and end points. E.g. by rotating or skewing the rect so that I would get a rect which has the same length and the same direction as the line.

Answer (score 2):

**lineToPath** converts an SVG `<line>` to a closed `<path>` using the line's start and end points and stroke width:

```js
const lineToPath = ({x1,y1,x2,y2,width}) => {
  const angle = Math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
  const dx = width / 2 * -Math.sin(angle);
  const dy = width / 2 * Math.cos(angle);
  
  return `M ${x1 + dx},${y1 + dy} L ${x2 + dx},${y2 + dy} 
    L ${x2 - dx},${y2 - dy} L ${x1 - dx},${y1 - dy} Z`;
}

const line = d3.select('line');
const x1 = parseFloat(line.attr('x1'));
const x2 = parseFloat(line.attr('x2'));
const y1 = parseFloat(line.attr('y1'));
const y2 = parseFloat(line.attr('y2'));
const width = parseFloat(line.attr('stroke-width'));

const linePath = lineToPath({x1,y1,x2,y2,width});
d3.select('path').attr('d', linePath);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <line x1="10" y1="90" x2="220" y2="30" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="30" />
  <path stroke="red" fill="none" />
</svg>
```